# React Native: fetch hanging when app became active after sleep

Tags: react-native

After the app resumes from deep sleep, all fetch requests hang. Any thoughts about what could be? The fetch requests are being called inside redux sagas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Cloudflare keeps the connection alive which was causing issues. I disabled it and now it is fine.